# TCP transfer not finishing: "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"?

Tags: c#, networking, tcp, tcpclient, tcplistener

I have a client application that uses a `TcpClient` to send a file to a server application that uses a `TcpListener` to receive it. Sometimes, the file transfers fine. But at other times, the transfer starts but does not finish. After I have read in a varying number of bytes on the server, I get an IOException with the message: "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."

On the client side, I create a header byte array containing data about my file, including the total size in bytes and a few other bits of data. I combine this byte array with that of the file, and send it to the server.

```
        TcpClient fileClient = new TcpClient();
        fileClient.Connect("mydomain.com", 7728);

        NetworkStream clientStream = fileClient.GetStream();
        ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
        FileStream fs = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open);

        string header = filePath + "|" + fs.Length.ToString() + "|" + this.ID); //ID = short string of mine
        header = header.PadRight(512, '*');
        byte[] sizeArray = encoder.GetBytes(header);

        byte[] fileBuffer = new byte[fs.Length];
        fs.Read(fileBuffer, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
        fs.Close();

        byte[] buffer = Combine(sizeArray, fileBuffer); //Combine = method I use to combine byte arrays
        clientStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        clientStream.Flush();
```

On the server side, I create a `TcpListener`, and start listening. When I get a connection, I handle it, read my header array, the first 512 bytes, determine the size of the new file, and then use this code to read the file / rest of the bytes:

```
        int newSize = ... //The size that I sent in my header array
        byte[] fileArray = new byte[newSize];

        int off = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                off += clientStream.Read(fileArray, off, fileArray.Length - off);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                off = newSize; // Enables partial receive on error, not total loss
            }
            if (off >= newSize)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
```

This is where it **sometimes** - about 25% of the time - goes wrong. I will get the exception at the `off += clientStream.Read(fileArray, off, fileArray.Length - off)` line. I surrounded it with a try catch, which enables the application to still get part of the file even when this error occurs. However, I need to be able to get the full file all the time. What am I doing wrong with this code?

The files I am transferring are JPEG images around 100KB in size, and generally take no more than two seconds to transfer on even the slowest of connections. Changing the timeout values for the clients and the listener does nothing to help.

Comment: 2 seconds to transfer 100K? are you using string for Ethernet cable?

Comment: It's almost always less, but the client application will sometimes be used by people on a truly pathetic connection

Comment: On the client side what do you do after the `.Flush`, e.g. just exit?

Comment: I don't do anything, the program keeps running and will send as many files as the user needs. I also tried removing the Flush line and it didn't change anything.

Comment: @MitchWheat: dialup still exists. ;)

Comment: Okay, the client keeps running after `.Flush` and the `fileClient` and `clientStream` instances are never disposed. I had thought there might be a possibility that they went out of scope and resulted in the connection closing.

Comment: You don't need to do most of this. You can send your header separately from the file data, and you can send the file data a chunk at a time, instead of reading the entire thing into memory. In your server code you are ignoring the possibility of premature EOS when reading. In short the code needs a lot of work. But the exception is clear enough surely. What's the question?